# Why is MOD17A3 GPP is showing huge values in R?

Tags: raster, r, modis

I have downloaded Gpp_1km (MOD17A3.055)data from MOD17A3 thorugh https://lpdaacsvc.cr.usgs.gov/appeears/ from the years 2000-2010. However when I opened all the tif files in R, each tif file showed the same maximum and minimum value (-2147483648, 2147483647). I am very confused about this.

How come there is no change in GPP from the period of 2000-2010?

Secondly the GPP is supposed to be in the units of kg C m−2 yr −1.

How come these values of tif are so large?

My study area shapefile is available at http://rds.icimod.org/Home/DataDetail?metadataId=3924

The following is GPP of 2010:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2804, 5303, 14869612  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.325  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/Halima Usman/Downloads/GPPMODIS/GPP2010.tif 
names      : GPP2010 
values     : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)
```

and all the rest of the tif files are identical to this one.

I would like to know how come the GPP never changes from 2000-2010 and why are the values coming so large?

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers:

```
values     : -2147483648, 2147483647  (min, max)
```

are the smallest and largest signed integers that can be stored in 32 bits of data. These values are often used in image data to denote missing data, or otherwise bad values. This should be detailed in any descriptive metadata or help supplied with the data.

You can investigate this yourself if you can't find anything in the help. Try plotting a map of where the raster has these values, or anything greater than plus or minus 2000000000. It might then be obvious that this is,for example, sea area where your data is only meaningful on land. Once you figure that out, you might want to replace the large numbers with R's `NA` value to show it is missing or bad data.

Otherwise unless you can share your TIFF I can't suggest much more.

Comment: Basically, I would like to know how to apply a scale factor in R. I edited my question.

Comment: You've fundamentally changed your question after I answered the original question. This makes my answer look wrong. I've reverted your edits back to the original question. You should ask a *new* question if your edit substantially changes the question.